# Prove that a graph on $n$ vertices with girth $g$ has at most $\frac{g}{g-2}(n-2)$ edges

Tags: graph-theory

I'm not sure how to go about this. One of my thoughts was to take the number of edges in a complete graph, and subtract all of the edges that would be needed to make a smaller cycle.

If you have $C_5$, there is only one way to make a $5$-cycle on $5$ vertices, but there's $10$ ways to make a $3$-cycle, and...

I have no idea how to do this without counting things multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

This isn’t true as stated: the [Petersen graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph) has $10$ vertices, $15$ edges, and girth $5$, and

$$15>\frac{40}3=\frac53(10-2)\;.$$

It *is* true for *planar* graphs.

HINT: Use [Euler’s formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Euler.27s_formula), $v-e+f=2$, where $v,e$, and $f$ are the numbers of vertices, edges, and faces, respectively, of a planar graph when it is embedded in the plane without any edge intersections.

If that’s not enough, here’s a further hint:

> Count each edge once for each face in which it appears. Do this in two different ways, once by edges and once by faces, to get an inequality involving $e,f$, and $g$, and then use Euler’s formula to eliminate $f$. Finally, solve the inequality for $g$.

And the complete solution, bar a bit of algebra at the end.

> Each face has at least $g$ edges. If you count each edge once for each face in which it appears, you get $2e$ when you count by edges, since each edge appears in $2$ faces, and you get a minimum of $gf$ when you count by faces. Thus, $2e\ge gf=g(2-v+e)$. Now solve this inequality for $e$.

Comment: Thanks - but that doesn't make sense to me at all. With the last hint, how do you go from the left side of the equality to the right side, with 2e≥gf = g(2−v+e) ?

Comment: @alecr: Basic algebra: you have $2e\ge 2g-gv+ge$, so $ge-2e\le gv-2g$, i.e., $(g-2)e\le g(v-2)$. Now divide through by $g-2$ to get $$e\le \frac{g}{g-2}(v-2)\;.$$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott why does each face have at least g edges?