# proving bound on edges using Euler formula

Tags: graph-theory

I want to prove the following result

> Every $n$-vertex planar graph with $n\geq3$ and with girth $g$ has at most $\frac{g}{g-2}(n-2)$ edges.

Any hints? I have no idea. I don't see any useful link between the girth and the number of edges.

Comment: This is not true. The complete graph $K_5$ has 10 edges and girth 3. The claim is that it has at most 9 edges. I think you mean for the graph to be planar. In the planar case you can relate girth to the degree of the vertices in the dual graph.

Comment: sorry :( planar of course

Comment: apparently it can be done using Euler's formula. Any idea how that would work?

Comment: See this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2000967/24947).